# Get data from API to Kibana dashboard

Tags: api, elasticsearch, kibana

How can i get data from API

http://ivivaanywhere.ivivacloud.com/api/Asset/Asset/All?apikey=SC:demo:64a9aa122143a5db&max=10&last=0

to kibana dashboard?